# What is and what's the use of the Closure "directive"

Tags: groovy, closures

I see in the docs and in Closure.java references to "directive" with no explanation of whgat it is or what it is for,

```
public static final int DONE = 1, SKIP = 2;
private int directive;
/**
 * @return Returns the directive.
 */
public int getDirective() {
    return directive;
}

/**
 * @param directive The directive to set.
 */
public void setDirective(int directive) {
    this.directive = directive;
}
```

I also googled it but I found not a single reference to it, except from some tests where it appears

```
assert directive = DONE
```

so the only thing I know is that it can be DONE or SKIP.

Is there any "real life" example of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This directive property is used internally from the groovy runtime as a loop break condition in collect operations
see **groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.java** in groovy source code:

```
    public static <T,E> Collection<T> collect(Collection<E> self, Collection<T> collector, @ClosureParams(FirstParam.FirstGenericType.class) Closure<? extends T> transform) {
    for (E item : self) {
        collector.add(transform.call(item));
        if (transform.getDirective() == Closure.DONE) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return collector;
}
```

It is accessible via the getter and setter getDirective() and setDirective() in groovy runtime
and via the **directive** property of the closure in your script.

**DONE** is used to stop the collect operation

For example to stop after 5:

```
(1..10).collect { 
    if (it>= 5) directive = Closure.DONE;
    new Tuple(it, (int)(it/2) )
}

Result: [[1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 2], [5, 2]]
```

**SKIP** is not used ... and has no effect on the collect operation (?!)

This feature sounds a bit like a trick for special cases 
it is probably better to use collection methods like find, findAll etc.
if possible

Comment: That's very good, and since directive is a int I can use my own directives to handle complex logic inside the closure, like
`(1..10).collect {      
    if (directive == 189){
        directive = 190
        new Tuple(it, (int)(it/2) ) 
    }else{
        directive = 189
        new Tuple(it, (int)(it*2) ) 
    }
}​`
Thanks, I appreciate the concise and clear response.

Comment: ur welcome. 
if I were you I wouldn't do that, too complex and difficult to maintain IMHO ...you would prepare yourself hard time in the future
Is it related to another question you have posted about DSL ?
if yes I have a response to submit, I started working on some DSL-like tool and digging the subject