# Break out of Groovy 'times' loop

Tags: groovy, soapui

Is is possible to break out of the times loop. Something like:

```
5.times {  
    // do some stuff 
    if (status != "OK") { 
        break 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is and what's the use of the Closure "directive"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38609088/what-is-and-whats-the-use-of-the-closure-directive)

Comment: Yet using `directive = Closure.DONE` is basically undocumented and so obscure, i'd never rely on that. Just do what `times` does: do a `for` loop and break.